# Custom PSTricks directory tree to TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, tikz-trees, foreach

I have a `PSTricks` implementation of a custom directory tree which I find quite appealing. I basically want to convert the whole thing to `TikZ`. I managed to get the very basic idea running in `TikZ`: I can create a directory and a file. But I have no idea how to position them relative to the previous item. I do know of the [`dirtree`](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/dirtree/dirtree.pdf) package but I do like the symbols for files and directories.

In the PSTricks code a new paragraph is added with `\par` for each new item (file or directory). In `TikZ` I do have to position the individual nodes relative to each other I guess. Therefore, I have to save the last node name or location. How can this be done? Or is there a complete other way?

**Working PSTricks code**

Credits to J. Stier

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node, pstricks-add}

% ---------------------------
% PST-Directory-Tree
% ---------------------------

% Counter
\newcounter{leaves}
\newcounter{directories}
\newlength{\parskipnew}
\setlength{\parskipnew}{\parskip}

% Environment
\newenvironment{directory}[2][\linewidth]{%
  \setcounter{leaves}{0}%
  \addtocounter{directories}{1}%
  \edef\directoryname{D\thedirectories}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{#1}%
\setlength{\parindent}{\linewidth}%
\addtolength{\parindent}{-\dirshrink\parindent}%
\parskip2pt%
\noindent%
\Rnode[href=-\dirshrink]{\directoryname}{%
  \parbox[t]{#1}{%
  \parbox[c]{0.65cm}{%
    \centering%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Figures/Icons/ordner}%
  }%
  \hspace{.2em}\texttt{#2}}%
}%
\par
}
{\end{minipage}\vspace{0.5\parskipnew}}

% Commands
\newcommand{\file}[2][]{%
  \addtocounter{leaves}{1}%
  \edef\leaflabel{L\theleaves\directoryname}%
  \par
  \Rnode{\leaflabel}{%
\parbox[t]{\dirshrink\linewidth}{%
  \parbox[c]{0.65cm}{%
    \centering\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Figures/Icons/datei}%
  }%
  \hspace{.2em}\texttt{#2}\hfill#1}%
}%
  \ncangle[angleA=270,angleB=180,armB=0,nodesepA=3pt,nodesepB=2pt]{\directoryname}{\leaflabel}%
  \par%
}
% 
\newcommand{\dir}[2][]{%
  \addtocounter{leaves}{1}%
  \edef\leaflabel{L\theleaves\directoryname}%
  \par
  \Rnode{\leaflabel}{%
\parbox[t]{\dirshrink\linewidth}{%
  \parbox[c]{0.65cm}{%
    \centering%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Figures/Icons/ordner}%
  }%
  \hspace{.2em}\texttt{#2}\hfill#1%
}%
  }%
  \ncangle[angleA=270,angleB=180,armB=0,nodesepA=3pt,nodesepB=2pt]{\directoryname}{\leaflabel}%
  \par%
}
% 
\newcommand{\fother}[2][]{%
  \addtocounter{leaves}{1}%
  \edef\leaflabel{L\theleaves\directoryname}%
  \par
  \Rnode{\leaflabel}{%
\parbox[t]{\dirshrink\linewidth}{%
  \hspace{0.5em}\normalfont{\textit{#2}}\hfill#1
}%
  }%
  \ncangle[angleA=270,angleB=180,armB=0,nodesepA=3pt,nodesepB=2pt]{\directoryname}{\leaflabel}%
  \par%
}
% 
\newcommand{\dirfile}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{leaves}{1}%
  \edef\leaflabel{L\theleaves\directoryname}%
  \par
  \Rnode{\leaflabel}{%
\parbox[t]{\dirshrink\linewidth}{#1}%
  }%
  \ncangle[angleA=270,angleB=180,armB=0,nodesepA=3pt,nodesepB=2pt]{\directoryname}{\leaflabel}%
  \par%
}
%
\newcommand{\dirshrink}{0.967}
%
\newcommand{\optional}[1]{{\normalfont\mdseries$<$\hspace{0.05em}{\itshape #1}\hspace{0.15em}$>$}}

% ---------------------------
% Document
% ---------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(6,12.5)
\psset{linewidth=0.5pt}
\rput[lb](0,0.5){
\begin{directory}{\optional{Project}}
\dirfile{%
  \begin{directory}{Figures}
    \file{fig-1.eps}
    \file{fig-1.pdf}
    \file{fig-1.png}
    \file{fig-2.eps}
    \file{fig-2.pdf}
    \file{fig-2.png}
  \end{directory}%
}
% %
\dirfile{%
  \begin{directory}{Scripts}
    \file{install\_package\_A.sh}
    \file{install\_package\_B.sh}
    \file{install\_package\_C.sh}
  \end{directory}
}
% %
\dirfile{%
  \begin{directory}{Sections}
    \file{section-1.tex}
    \file{section-2.tex}
    \file{section-3.tex}
    \file{literature.bib}
  \end{directory}
}
% %
\file{project.kilepr}
\file{project.tex}
% % 
\end{directory}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: PSTricks result]

**Initial TikZ code**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{pstricks, pst-node, pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% ---------------------------
% PST-Directory-Tree
% ---------------------------

% Counter
\newcounter{leaves}
\newcounter{directories}
\newlength{\parskipnew}
\setlength{\parskipnew}{\parskip}

% Environment
\newenvironment{directory}[2][\linewidth]{%
  \setcounter{leaves}{0}%
  \addtocounter{directories}{1}%
  \edef\directoryname{D\thedirectories}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{#1}%
    \setlength{\parindent}{\linewidth}%
    \addtolength{\parindent}{-\dirshrink\parindent}%
    \parskip2pt%
    \noindent%
    \node (i1\directoryname) {\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Figures/Icons/ordner}};
    \node[right = .2em of i1\directoryname] (i2\directoryname) {\texttt{#2}};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \node[fit={(i1\directoryname) (i2\directoryname)}, fill=lightgray, inner sep=0pt] (\directoryname) {};
    \end{scope}
}
{\end{minipage}\vspace{0.5\parskipnew}}

% Commands
\newcommand{\file}[2][]{%
  \addtocounter{leaves}{1}%
  \edef\leaflabel{L\theleaves\directoryname}%
  \node[below right= 0.5ex and 0.5em of \directoryname.south](i1\leaflabel) {\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Figures/Icons/datei}};%
  \node[right = .2em of i1\leaflabel] (i2\leaflabel) {\texttt{#2}};
  \node[fit={(i1\leaflabel) (i2\leaflabel)}, inner sep=0pt] (\leaflabel) {};
  \draw (\directoryname.south) |- (\leaflabel.west);
}
%
\newcommand{\dirshrink}{0.967}
%
\newcommand{\optional}[1]{{\normalfont\mdseries$<$\hspace{0.05em}{\itshape #1}\hspace{0.15em}$>$}}

% ---------------------------
% Document
% ---------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}(10,10)
  \begin{directory}{\optional{Project}}
    \file{fig-1.eps}
    \file{fig-2.eps}
  \end{directory}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Necessary image files**

[image: datei.png]
[image: ordner.png]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just realised you supplied images for the icons. Oh, well. Here is a pure TikZ solution. At least, it uses **forest** which is based on TikZ. In addition, it uses two `pic`s for the icons, which are then used within the tree.

This makes use of the new `edges` library for **forest** which includes a `folder` style for directory trees. It can draw the folders, too, but they are not terribly folder or file like, so would probably not meet your expectations. Here, the style is just used to automate the structural appearance of the tree.

This is *much* easier with the `edges` library, as this used to require setting up a suitable tree style.

Load packages and the library we want.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\begin{document}
```

Apply the defaults from the `edges` library. If you plan to draw other kinds of trees, put this within a TeX group to limit the scope.

```
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{edges}
```

We create two `pic`s for the icons.

```
\tikzset{%
```

For folder shapes, `mkdir`.

```
  mkdir/.pic={%
    \draw [pic actions] (-1.5ex,-1ex) -- ++(0,2ex) -- ++(.25ex,.25ex) -- ++(1.25ex,0) -- ++(.25ex,-.25ex) -- ++(1.25ex,0) |- cycle;
  },
```

For file shapes, `touch`.

```
  touch/.pic={%
    \draw [pic actions] (-1ex,-1.5ex) |- ++(1.25ex,3ex) edge ++(.75ex,-.75ex) |- ++(.75ex,-.75ex) |- cycle;
  }
}
```

Now a **forest**-specific style, `optional` which we'll use in place of `\optional{}`.

```
\forestset{%
  optional/.style={%
    content/.wrap value={$<$\hspace{0.05em}\normalfont\itshape ##1\hspace{0.15em}$>$},
  }
}
```

Now for the actual tree, in the `forest` environment.

```
\begin{forest}
```

First some customisation.

```
  for tree={
```

Apply these settings to the entire tree.

```
    font=\ttfamily,
```

We want the tree to grow to the right i.e. at an angle of `0` and we need to reverse the order of the children else it comes out upside down.

```
    grow'=0,
```

Apply the `folder` style, which sets up the `pstree` type structure.

```
    folder,
```

All of the terminal nodes are files, while all of the others are directories. So, we can automatically add the icons by testing whether each node has any children (non-terminal) or not (terminal).

```
    if n children=0{
```

We need to delay the adjustment a bit, so the original content is set. Then we'll add some space on the left to make room for the icon.

```
      before typesetting nodes={
        content/.wrap value={\hspace*{2.5ex}#1},
      },
```

We'll add a TikZ annotation which will draw the `pic` for the icon in the relevant place. `tikz`'s value specifies code which will be passed to TikZ as-is after the tree is drawn, but before the `forest` environment is ended. The context of the relevant node is still available and we can use e.g. `(.west)` to access the `west` anchor of the current node in order to place the `pic` appropriately.

```
      tikz={%
        \pic [xshift=1.5ex] at (.west) {touch};
      }
    }{
```

Now we do the same for the non-terminal nodes. Only the spacing and the `pic` vary here.

```
      before typesetting nodes={
        content/.wrap value={\hspace*{3.5ex}#1},
      },
      tikz={%
        \pic [xshift=2ex] at (.west) {mkdir};
      }
    }
  },
```

Now for the tree itself, starting with the root which we want to apply the `optional` style to.

```
  [Project, optional
```

First sub-directory

```
    [Figures
```

and its contents, which are child nodes in tree-speak.

```
      [fig-1.eps]
      [fig-1.pdf]
      [fig-1.png]
      [fig-2.eps]
      [fig-2.pdf]
      [fig-2.png]
    ]
```

End first sub-directory. Start the second sub-directory, which is the second child of the tree's root node.

```
    [Scripts
```

And its contents are children, as before.

```
      [install\_package\_A.sh]
      [install\_package\_B.sh]
      [install\_package\_C.sh]
    ]
```

Continue adding sub-directories and their contents.

```
    [Sections
      [section-1.tex]
      [section-2.tex]
      [section-3.tex]
      [literature.bib]
    ]
```

The last two entries are at the level just below the root, but these are themselves files i.e. children of the root which are also terminal nodes.

```
    [project.kilepr]
    [project.tex]
```

Close the root.

```
  ]
```

And finish the tree.

```
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: directory tree with forest v2]

## REVISED VERSION

We might, however, want more flexibility. For example, we might want to more easily alter the size of the icons/symbols for the files and directories, and to control the distances between the path and the icon, on the one hand, and the icon and the name, on the other.

We can do this with a slightly more power set of TikZ settings and some modifications to the **forest** code. The trickiest part of this, for me, turned out to be figuring out how to use multiples of dimensions inside `forest`. For example, how to tell it to shift something by 10 times a particular length or whatever. Eventually, I used a scratch dimension register for this, but I'm not sure this is the most efficient solution.

We start, as before, with some TikZ customisation.

```
\tikzset{%
```

We want some macros to hold various dimensions so they can be easily modified. We'll use 4 macros for this.

- `\mkdirsize` for the base size of the directory icon (width = 12 x base size);
- `touchsize` for the base size of the file icon (width = 8 x base size);
- `\iconsep` for the distance between the icon and the name;
- `\iconsepfrompath` for the distance between the path and the icon.

These will be modifiable as TikZ styles.

- `mkdir size`;
- `touch size`;
- `icon sep`;
- `icon sep from path`.

Here's the configuration:

```
  mkdir size/.store in=\mkdirsize,
  touch size/.store in=\touchsize,
  icon sep/.store in=\iconsep,
  icon sep from path/.store in=\iconsepfrompath,
```

We make sure everything has a default value.

```
  mkdir size=.25ex,
  touch size=.25ex,
  icon sep=1.5ex,
  icon sep from path=1ex,
```

Now we want our `pic`s to be based on the values of `mkdir size` and `touch size`.

We also put the left-most point of each `pic` at `x=0` rather than shifting it left because this makes it easier to adjust the location of the icons correctly within the tree.

```
  mkdir/.pic={%
    \draw [pic actions] (0,-4*\mkdirsize) -- ++(0,8*\mkdirsize) -- ++(\mkdirsize,\mkdirsize) -- ++(5*\mkdirsize,0) -- ++(\mkdirsize,-\mkdirsize) -- ++(5*\mkdirsize,0) |- cycle;
  },
  touch/.pic={%
    \draw [pic actions] (0,-6*\touchsize) |- ++(5*\touchsize,12*\touchsize) edge ++(3*\touchsize,-3*\touchsize) |- ++(3*\touchsize,-3*\touchsize) |- cycle;
  },
}
```

We also want to adapt the preamble of the tree to use the values of `icon sep` and `icon sep from path`.

```
\begin{forest}
```

We start off as before, however.

```
  for tree={
    font=\ttfamily,
    grow'=0,
    folder,
```

The changes come in specifying where the nodes should be and the space which should be inserted before the main node content. This bit is the bit I had trouble with. This works, but it may not be the most effective or efficient solution.

```
    if n children=0{
      before typesetting nodes={
```

We use a scratch register dimension to calculate how much space to add to the node content.

```
        tempdima=\iconsepfrompath+\iconsep+8*\touchsize,
        content/.wrap value={\expandafter\hskip \foresteregister{tempdima}#1},
      },
```

We then need to also shift the `pic` to the right by the appropriate amount.

```
      tikz={%
        \pic [xshift=\iconsepfrompath] at (.west) {touch};
      },
    }{
```

There's a complication in the case of the directory nodes, because one of these is at the root and the `pic` ought not be shifted right here, and less space should be added to the content of the node. So we deal with this case separately.

```
      if level=0{
```

Don't shift the directory symbol.

```
        tikz={%
          \pic at (.west) {mkdir};
        },
```

Add the space to the node, but don't add the value of `icon sep from path` as this is irrelevant for the root directory.

```
        before typesetting nodes={
          tempdima=\iconsep+12*\mkdirsize,
          content/.wrap value={\expandafter\hskip \foresteregister{tempdima}#1},
        },
```

Now for the non-root directories.

```
      }{
        tikz={%
          \pic [xshift=\iconsepfrompath] at (.west) {mkdir};
        },
        before typesetting nodes={
          tempdima=\iconsepfrompath+\iconsep+12*\mkdirsize,
          content/.wrap value={\expandafter\hskip \foresteregister{tempdima}#1},
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

[image: revised directory tree with **forest** <code>edges</code> library]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\begin{document}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{edges}
\tikzset{%
  mkdir/.pic={%
    \draw [pic actions] (0,-4*\mkdirsize) -- ++(0,8*\mkdirsize) -- ++(\mkdirsize,\mkdirsize) -- ++(5*\mkdirsize,0) -- ++(\mkdirsize,-\mkdirsize) -- ++(5*\mkdirsize,0) |- cycle;
  },
  touch/.pic={%
    \draw [pic actions] (0,-6*\touchsize) |- ++(5*\touchsize,12*\touchsize) edge ++(3*\touchsize,-3*\touchsize) |- ++(3*\touchsize,-3*\touchsize) |- cycle;
  },
  mkdir size/.store in=\mkdirsize,
  touch size/.store in=\touchsize,
  icon sep/.store in=\iconsep,
  icon sep from path/.store in=\iconsepfrompath,
  mkdir size=.25ex,
  touch size=.25ex,
  icon sep=1.5ex,
  icon sep from path=1ex,
}
\forestset{%
  optional/.style={%
    content/.wrap value={$<$\hspace{0.05em}\normalfont\itshape ##1\hspace{0.15em}$>$},
  },
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\ttfamily,
    grow'=0,
    folder,
    if n children=0{
      before typesetting nodes={
        tempdima=\iconsepfrompath+\iconsep+8*\touchsize,
        content/.wrap value={\expandafter\hskip \foresteregister{tempdima}#1},
      },
      tikz={%
        \pic [xshift=\iconsepfrompath] at (.west) {touch};
      },
    }{
      if level=0{
        tikz={%
          \pic at (.west) {mkdir};
        },
        before typesetting nodes={
          tempdima=\iconsep+12*\mkdirsize,
          content/.wrap value={\expandafter\hskip \foresteregister{tempdima}#1},
        },
      }{
        tikz={%
          \pic [xshift=\iconsepfrompath] at (.west) {mkdir};
        },
        before typesetting nodes={
          tempdima=\iconsepfrompath+\iconsep+12*\mkdirsize,
          content/.wrap value={\expandafter\hskip \foresteregister{tempdima}#1},
        },
      },
    },
  },
  [Project, optional
    [Figures
      [fig-1.eps]
      [fig-1.pdf]
      [fig-1.png]
      [fig-2.eps]
      [fig-2.pdf]
      [fig-2.png]
    ]
    [Scripts
      [install\_package\_A.sh]
      [install\_package\_B.sh]
      [install\_package\_C.sh]
    ]
    [Sections
      [section-1.tex]
      [section-2.tex]
      [section-3.tex]
      [literature.bib]
    ]
    [project.kilepr]
    [project.tex]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, that looks great. I have no experience with forest, so I have two short questions: Is it possible to modify the vertical margin between the entries? I tried `l sep-=1em` from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167973/specifying-the-distance-between-levels-in-forest but this seems to effect the horizontal margin instead of the vertical. The second question: is it possible to position some files, e.g. fig-1.eps fig-1.pdf and fig-1.png next to each other horizontally to save some vertical space?

Comment: The calibration of the vertical margin can be achieved with `s sep-=0.25ex` in the `for tree={s sep-=0.25ex,...}` definition

Comment: One more question: I tried to scale the `touch` and `mkdir` `tikzset` using a `scalebox` but this totally messed up the positions of the images. Why is that? I tought the position would be fixed at `(.west)`

Comment: @krtek I'm not sure quite how you are trying to use it. But I would instead add `scale=<whatever>` to the options you give `\pic` e.g. `\pic [xshift=2ex, scale=.5] at (.west) {mkdir};` or whatever. You might also then want to adjust the value of `xshift` and the amount of space in the corresponding `\hspace*{}` command to accommodate the change in scaling.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that tomorrow. Does `forest` allow to position several file entries side by side horizontally?

Comment: @krtek Please see revised version above which makes it easy to change the size of the `pic`s and to specify the distance between `pic` and path and `pic` and name.

Comment: @krtek For your new question: **forest** allows you to do pretty much anything TikZ can do, in addition to the tree-specific stuff. However, that's really a different question and not the kind of thing which can be addressed in comments. It would be better to ask a new question so that solutions will consider that requirement from the beginning, rather than asking it here. (Maybe this can be adapted, but it depends on the details. I mean, you could just add to the tree after drawing it. But I didn't plan for that as it was never mentioned, so I didn't provide a specific interface.)

Comment: I agree. I will first have a deeper look into `forest` myself and then eventually ask a new question. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really answer your question but I find it is a useful layout that one can easily maintain and manipulate. It also allows for some non-standard structure. I haven't worked out how to include file icons just yet. It also works best if you keep the tab control columns reasonably well aligned.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{menukeys}

\newmenumacro{\nixfile}[/]{hyphenatepaths}
\newmenumacro{\nixpath}[/]{hyphenatepathswithfolder}
\newmenumacro{\winpath}[bslash]{hyphenatepathswithfolder}
\newmenumacro{\winfile}[bslash]{hyphenatepaths}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{1em}\=\hspace{1em}\=\hspace{1em}\=\hspace{12em}\=\\\kill
\nixpath{root/path } \>\>\>\>  Main Root                                 \+\\
\nixpath{subfolder }   \>\>\>  Specialized subfolder                     \+\\
\nixfile{subfile   }     \>\>  Some file                                 \-\\
\nixfile{wierd/file}   \>\>\>  Important subfile, unimportant subfolders   \\
\nixfile{file      }   \>\>\>  Main file                                   \\
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Typical output showing non-standard tree items]