# Reduce level height (and also horizontal separation) in Forest

Tags: forest

This is probably a stupid question for anyone well-versed in TikZ, but I'm not well-versed in TikZ and just want to create som simple tree structures. Hoping for a quick fix.

My trees typically have no labels on internal nodes, just leaves. I tried qtree like this:

```
{\newcommand{\qleafhook}{\scriptsize}
\Tree [.
[ [ 0 1 ] [ 2 3  ] ]
[ [ 4 [ 5 6 ] ] [ [ 7 8 ] [ 9 10 ] ] ]
]
}
```

Pretty nice, almost what I want, except that I'd like nodes on the same depth be aligned horizontally, i.e., I'd like just two leaf levels here: one for 0 to 4 (which have depth 3), and another for 5 to 10 (which have depth 4).

[image: qtree version]

It didn't seem like qtree was designed for fixing this, so I switched to trying forest. I quickly arrived at this:

```
{\scriptsize
\begin{forest}
  [, for tree={parent anchor=north, child anchor=north}
  [ [ [0] [1] ] [ [2] [3]  ] ]
  [ [ [4] [ [5] [6] ] ] [ [ [7] [8] ] [ [9] [10] ] ] ]
  ]
\end{forest}
}
```

This is exactly what I want, except that it's *huge*, lots of space for the edge labels that don't exist, and also more horizontal space than I would like.

[image]

Is there an easy way to squash this down? When I fiddle around with `l` and `l sep`, it breaks the vertical alignment I want, and also doesn't have that much effect. I understand that I could find how to do it if I took a deep dive in the Forest and/or TikZ manuals, but I'm hoping there's something relatively simple that I'm missing, that somebody could point out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The perhaps simplest way to reduce the level distance is to add `l+=<something negative>` but this does not allow you to make the distance arbitrarily small. To improve on that you can [pass these options to the children](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188461/121799).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={parent anchor=north, child anchor=north,font=\scriptsize,fit=tight,
for children={l sep-=1.5em,l-=1.5em}}
  [
  [ [ [0] [1] ] [ [2] [3]  ] ]
  [ [ [4] [ [5] [6] ] ] [ [ [7] [8] ] [ [9] [10] ] ] ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want something closer to your first picture, fix the edge angles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={parent anchor=north, child anchor=north,font=\scriptsize,fit=tight,
calign=fixed edge angles,calign angle=70,
for children={l sep-=2em,l-=2em}}
  [
  [ [ [0] [1] ] [ [2] [3]  ] ]
  [ [ [4] [ [5] [6] ] ] [ [ [7] [8] ] [ [9] [10] ] ] ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, some stuff to play around with in your example there. I'll make do with that for now in combination with resizebox, in the absence of The Perfect Solution.